# IIS Express failing to start on localhost with ipv6

Tags: ipv6, iis-express, ipv4

Hello fine Stackoverflow users!

Here's something funny that's happened to me - maybe you can explain why?

Half way through my workday yesterday my installation of IIS Express stopped working.

At first I thought it was a problem with the ASP.NET project I was working on, just hanging and failing to start, because the page continued to hang until it timed out. Then I tried some other projects, also set up to run on localhost:8080 - and they wouldn't load either - even plain HTML ones.

Now, when I say that they wouldn't load; I mean no activity at all. The page would "load" in chrome for ages, and the IISExpress console wouldn't register any GET requests, until eventually the tab in chrome would display a timeout error.

This morning, I (with some help) figured something out - for some reason when I pinged `localhost` the ipv6 address `::1:` would return instead of the ipv4 address `127.0.0.1` - I hadn't noticed this behaviour before, and I haven't changed any networking settings.

I edited my HOST file, and included an entry for `127.0.0.1 localhost` to force `ping localhost` to return the ipv4 address. This worked, and when I tried IIS Express again binding to localhost:8080 it also worked.

*My question is*; **What On Earth?!?!**

I have no idea why this has happened. I know I've managed to fix the individual problem by editing my HOST file, but does anyone know why on earth this would have happened?

Any idea why `ping localhost` would suddenly start returning the ipv6 address? And any idea why IIS Express wouldn't work with ipv6? (I assume the IIS engine would have that baked in by now).

I'd like to understand what's happened to avoid any further problems, and for curiosities sake.

Thanks in advance for any info,

Phil

Answer (score 3):

- Open an admin cmd window, then execute this with the port you're binding to: `netsh http add urlacl url="http://[::1]:8080/" user=everyone`. This tells your system that it's cool to bind to `::1`
- Open `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`, find your site's section, and add the IPv6 binding: **`<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="[::1]:8080:*" />`**

Sample:

`<site name="WebSite1" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\ryan.versaw\Documents\WebSite1" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="[::1]:8080:*" />
    </bindings>
</site>`

Answer (score 0):

As long as IPv6 is enabled on your system, ::1 and 127.0.0.0 are both valid addresses for 'localhost'. Which of the two is returned by the system and used for e.g. pings is more or less nondeterministic, unless a programme specifically requests an IPv4 or an IPv6 address - and since Windows' ping can handle either, it probably didn't do that.

As for IIS, answers like this one suggest this behaviour is on purpose and you need to enable binding to an IPv6 address separately: https://serverfault.com/questions/123796/get-iis-7-5-to-listen-on-ipv6